# every $\sigma$ set is 0-dimensional.

Tags: general-topology

X is a $\sigma$set if it is a separable metric space such that every $F_\sigma$ set is also a $G_\delta$ set; i.e. every Borel set is both $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$.

A topological space is zero-dimensional if each point has a neighbourhood base consisting of both open and closed sets.

In the proof of the statement,([page 117, Lemma 5.3](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271523/1-s2.0-S0166864100X02842/1-s2.0-S0166864101001742/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHsaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDwdPzIyhLyMVWeqi2HYNjgcIYDzig2ssq%2BmKf6vaP0EQIgQYzjH3TtOe7aQTotPPCDypnHe64gJPVtrBYFAPnVR8MqvAUIo%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDJoR8DVG%2FyojIOXhuyqQBXPHusY%2FtVRqu0tWzRot6axsukXXQGSmqNzUF3KCh0nhSJALs6gAoD%2BqB6VBLqxudtfbGRJGA2g18Udl7Zb21wNkh6a59Y8tRQLKwtMeC0fADcM1Z5LNT%2B3gq6QfCH3vRK92MsHsKB7%2BVnjcP25yhnTxMpqr%2B2M8ogfWsuAZQX5iCglABKXEoz6qjQCo0PTpBmEOjx9KxFv6qwNmGQs6ZEV6x4qN3M6eXzdm2Ty8Sucgq6vxLGEyOM0tSynQ589xZzbx8q2IO2RaHp3GJa9KZHyMrWcpmEN0pWe%2FJv4ni5e9yBzXnrllZxqvZXCoBjRBHUXnZHaMTNWTt1ShaRMBHzl%2BDIznxjHU3DouEB94vv%2BCdWip1eLxkGRfn3yXcQMcbcEECvO2nDF4XcrO7jhcVlsaoQIkPYkwfNZA9gtgO1IV5DRXg1OpvuYx7PEuoOm1wYlzI%2F4W0Abguu%2BgXbbH17CuhQ6RzBkKOSOkHiQrd6%2BhKQEs3EufDJ3Y6rYwyBMfC4fRwN8qQdh%2FDaX0BPHMEGQZz%2Fn2SmC%2FPNuA8MwxMUxQZNA%2FV7MCq6fcoDRo%2B8GvzqtV6XH0xR%2FV0l0I2Z2RRtEUN19ljFIuEaev%2BB9pzD7AlWzUp7918gL%2FLAD9dI%2FRdjE18sC7RM1oPzlBwP1Bqr%2FExa%2FRZwvCo5duZzx0Cqr5toEXqJDL%2FoRFNBr6QErXqenGZPKx0UpbOqKUZlQ4HUb4s59MPqq3hKVVXtzehPCH9rzwLDTupyWEHXoagEcDsZC6oGZz5o5lmKS3ipWXcESXIylEEdwA6R8SVtQXh9RBs4lxDGMu%2Fv70K4hlKIjX%2F1N1LUD6qFCaotYng6FB2uYZW0%2FErGgMXiJcvgkpJb3pMK3A86kGOrEB3cf04Z3Iv4daigLSlJXD%2FRZ5S3mdNTM%2BvgSZiJytHB%2BMTh2586e%2BWPsefatftjE5hcqPVNT%2FRyrFTYkmVnpkZpmM0dq4ofQwXnCcr7hYXhNFuVrGRp4fjXF2uYu2bUFt5zxbXTDazOi5ImBcJPvUmZO%2BBT3oZ26WZPd8wsKTV%2FxAzGKbpbrjiPZKa1rSw0xPo7k1xNkku0fMf1ivftOt0%2BQbr4yXqFB01NgBNn0u9Ky8&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231028T111320Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYUI2X7EVS%2F20231028%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=73b2b5e9323cc5322306689171b018b08570d3dd2f46d576b2a12c4bbe06107a&hash=9808e85cafe9d4d58e5d18c4b801e3bbffcd08326b264eb33e43bff41a022529&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0166864101001742&tid=spdf-d421c916-ae79-4ecf-900e-8d648c1a932b&sid=0da9f5665f40f941420af2f76fc47df92442gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0f0856570a5106090151&rr=81d2bfb2c9a09a71&cc=in)) they said that
1)Continuous real-valued functions separate points from closed sets.
2) **no continuous function can map a $\sigma$set onto $[0,1]$ (or $\mathbb{R}$).** (reference: [page13, theorem 17](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eawmille1/res/survey.pdf))

I don't understand what is the meaning of statement 1). And can you please explain the proof or hint at the 2nd statement?

Comment: It means that for every closed set $Y\subseteq X$ and for every $x\in X$, there is a continuous function $f\colon X\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=0$ and $f(Y)=1$

Comment: Concerning statement 2):
At least around 1984 this seemed to be an open problem: see Handbook of set theoretic topology, article of A. Miller, p. 225: "Question. Is it consistent to have a $\sigma$-set X which can be mapped continuously onto the reals?".
Well, he defined a $\sigma$-set additionally to be a subset of the reals. But even with this stronger assumption, he considered it to be feasible that there is (consistently) such a mapping. On the other hand, I think it is known to be consistent that a $\sigma$-set (as defined by the OP) is countable.

Comment: Where did you find this proof / statement ? You just said "they". Could you please give a reference?

Comment: I have added the references; please have a look.

Comment: I assume you read Recław's proof cited in this paper. Then you should clearly say, what you didn't understand. It's not my topic, but others might be able to help you then.